# what is the purpose of the param key in the url of editting product in magento

Tags: php, magento, key, product

When i go to magento admin and edit product, i notice in the url like this

```
http://localhost/magento/index.php/admin/catalog_product/edit/id/881/key/49db070795d0e717abac7c40b0f23ee4/
```

magento sepcify the key, I want to know what is the purpose of the key, because the key are all the same with different product, dose it contain any information like store or something, and how magento generate this key for editing those products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a security feature to prevent fraud, nothing more...

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getSecretKey("adminhtml_yourcontroller","youraction");
```